# How to create Unique Id in Java

Tags: java, uuid

I have a code like below:

```
D00077B4-EBFB-4BD8-9E3F-1F3943CBCE35
```

I was wondering how I could generate a code like this in Java.

Comment: *what have you tried so far?* did you try to search on google?

Comment: @Lino How can you search for UUID on google if you don't know that it's called a UUID?

Comment: [Generating unique IDs](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56)?

Comment: That looks like a UUID

Comment: It might be an API key/token or something like that..

Comment: Can we generate UUID like the above using java?

Comment: try this then `UUID.randomUUID();`

Comment: @Aarivariv Did you read the page that MadProgrammer linked to?

Comment: Yep I got it @Lino. Thanks

Comment: @Aarivariv Why did you change the question to a more general (and thus too broad) one? It negates the given answers as they now do not fit the question anymore. I rolled it back!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), "a 128-bit number used to identify information in computer systems".

The format is explained as:

> In its canonical textual representation, the sixteen octets of a UUID are represented as 32 hexadecimal (base 16) digits, displayed in five groups separated by hyphens, in the form 8-4-4-4-12 for a total of 36 characters (32 alphanumeric characters and four hyphens). For example:

```
123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-Mxxx-Nxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

> How to generate the code like this using Java?

```
// Create a random UUID:
UUID uuid1 = UUID.randomUUID();
System.out.println(uuid1);

// Create a fixed UUID:
String uuidString = "D00077B4-EBFB-4BD8-9E3F-1F3943CBCE35";
UUID uuid2 = UUID.fromString(uuidString);
System.out.println(uuid2);

// Get string from UUID:
UUID uuid = ...
String s = uuid.toString();
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a GUID or UUID, you can read more here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

You can use java.util.UUID to generate one:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class RandomStringUUID {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creating a random UUID (Universally unique identifier).
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();

        System.out.println("Random UUID String = " + randomUUIDString);
        System.out.println("UUID version       = " + uuid.version());
        System.out.println("UUID variant       = " + uuid.variant());
    }
}
```